# Nodejs socket.io is showing webcam stream from client (angular12) as empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am sending a socket.io event holding different values including webcam stream but I am consoling the event data in nodejs and I am getting empty object. what can I do to get the stream.

If I console stream on client side before sending event I get it.

here is the client code (angular 12)

```js
  toggleVideoCall(){
    this.toggleVideo = false;
    
    let mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
    mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true
    })
    .then((stream:MediaStream)=>{
      this.addMyVideo(stream);
      console.log(stream);
      this.socket.emit("call", {callerStream: stream,callerName: this.myname,callerId: this.myId,recieverName: this.userToCall.username, reciever: this.userToCall._id});
    })
    .catch(alert)
  }
```

here is nodejs socket.io

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
 
      socket.on("call", (data)=>{
          console.log(data)
          io.emit("pickCall", data);
      })
})
```